# Immutable JS duplicate / copy List within Map

Tags: immutable.js

I have an Immutable Map like this

```
Immutable.fromJS({
    sortingOnFields: false,
    items: [],
    selectedItems: [], 
    columnsConfigs: {
        meta: {},
        columns: {}
    },
});
```

how do I copy the items List to selectedItems list.

This `return state.set('selectedItems', state.get('items'));`

doesn't do the job correctly as later if I do

```
props.listing.get('selectedItems').includes(Immutable.fromJS(item));
```

where `Immutable.fromJS(item)` is from the 'items' List, it returns false.

I tried this which works but looks a bit too much

```
return state.set('selectedItems', Immutable.fromJS(state.get('items').toJS()));
```

any ideas of a better solution?

Comment: Why would you want to copy items in that way? Surely it is better to have your items as a List and then store the index or ID of the items that are selected?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your test. You **are** successfully setting the same List at both keys. You're retrieving the value at `items`, which is a List, and you're setting that exact same List as the value at `selectedItems`.

Even though that *is* working, your test isn't doing its job. You wrote:

```
props.listing.get('selectedItems').includes(Immutable.fromJS(item));
```

That line says: Get the List at `selectedItems`. Now create a brand new Immutable object using the fromJS method. Does the List at selectedItems contain that new Immutable object? The answer is no, because you just created that item from scratch, so it is definitely not contained in the List at `selectedItems`.

If each item is a primitive value, you can just check like this:

```
props.listing.get('selectedItems').includes(item);
```

If each item is a object, then did you convert it to an Immutable object? If not, then you can pass in a reference to the item, as above. If you did convert it to an Immutable object, make sure you pass a reference to the correct Immutable equivalent to the `includes` method.